# Make Angular Material Grid Responsive (again)

Tags: angular, flexbox, grid, angular-material, angular-material-5

Angular material grid isn't responsive and it's columns are set in the template and/or you can set a variable and have a property binding. I'm attemping to use the latter approach where I have a

> public cols: Observable;

variable that I am over writing based on different window breaks. I'm following [this](http://brianflove.com/2017/05/03/responsive-angular/) article and have set up my code simililarly. But, my .map function comes up as **unresolved**

```
    ngOnInit(){
        const grid = new Map([
            ["xs", 1],
            ["sm", 2],
            ["md", 2],
            ["lg", 3],
            ["xl", 3]   ]);   let start: number;   grid.forEach((cols, mqAlias) => {
            if (this.observableMedia.isActive(mqAlias)) {
              start = cols;
            }   });   
  this.cols = this.observableMedia.asObservable().map(change => {
              console.log(change);
              console.log(grid.get(change.mqAlias));
              return grid.get(change.mqAlias);
            })
            .startWith(start);
    }
```

my imports are

```
import { ObservableMedia } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

I've also tried importing by

```
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import "rxjs/add/operator/startWith";
```

but that throws errors, i'm assuming it's due to angular 6.

Any help on why .map function is undefined and why I cannot dynamically change my **cols** variable value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RxJS v5.5.2+` has moved to **[Pipeable](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md)** operators to improve tree shaking and make it easier to create custom operators.
 now `operators` need to be  combined using the `pipe` method
**[Refer This](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-lettable-operators-fe74dda186d3)**
**New Import**

```
import { map} from 'rxjs/operators';
```

**Example**

```
myObservable
  .pipe(filter(data => data > 8),map(data => data * 2),)
  .subscribe(...);
```

**Modified Code**

```
 this.observableMedia.asObservable().pipe(map(change => {
              console.log(change);
              console.log(grid.get(change.mqAlias));
              return grid.get(change.mqAlias);
            }),startWith(start));
```

Comment: that worked perfectly. Thank you so much, i'll read more into the link you pasted.